# For an argument of the template class Foo method, is "Foo&" and "Foo<T>&" the same?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the class

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   Foo(const Foo<T>& other) {}
};
```

For the constructor argument type, is `const Foo<T>&` and `const Foo&` the same in this context? I always assumed not, thinking that the latter can be called for `Foo<int> f = Foo<float>()`, and the former cannot. But now I'm not sure if that is so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference when omitting the C++ template argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690506/difference-when-omitting-the-c-template-argument-list)

Comment: as the answers already say, yes that's legal. It's not ambigous because you cannot have both `class Foo` and `class Foo<T>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within a class template, class template parameters have one unique meaning for every instantiation. That means that `Foo<int>` has `T==int`, and thus the templated ctor is `Foo<int>::Foo(const Foo<int>& other)`.

It is possible to have *additional* template parameters, though :

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   template <typename U>
   Foo(const Foo<U>& other) {}
};
```

Now `T` can be different from `U`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's the same.

This is due to the *injected-class-name*. The class name is inserted into the scope of all classes so that name lookup acts sensibly. When the injected-class-name is used as a type name in a template class, it's equivalent to the template name followed by the template parameters enclosed in `<>` (`[temp.local]/1`), so `Foo` is equivalent to `Foo<T>` in that context.